# Very Green to Python

Tags: python

I am brand new to Python and very green as the title states, having a hard time wrapping my head around these 3 commands in Python:

1) while (counter >= 0):
 2) print counter
 3) counter = counter - 1

Could someone please point me into the right direction? 
Thank you

Comment: While counter is greater than zero, print counter and subtract one. When counter is no longer greater than zero, the while loop stops. Its pretty much just what the code szys.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic as it isn't a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) As long as your counter variable is greater or equal to 0. The while() is a conditional statement checking whether your counter is >= 0. If it is true, then it will execute the code in the while loop. If it's false, then it won't execute the code in the while loop.

2) print out the value of the counter variable

3) counter variable gets the value of : counter minus 1

Basically it says, as long as your counter variable is greater or equal to 0, then the program should print out the value of the counter, and then minus 1 from the value of the counter.

It will keep printing your counter value and minus 1 from your counter as long as your counter is greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: Thank you pythonhiew! Your detailed explanations really helped me wrap my head around this hence giving me a better understanding to move forward with python. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

This, given a number `x` so that `x >= 0`, will return all the integers between 0 and `x`, subtracted from `x`, inclusive:

```
def myfunc(x):
    while counter >= 0:
        print counter
        counter-=1 #Same as counter = counter-1
```

---

```
>>> myfunc(0)
0
>>> myfunc(4)
4
3
2
1
0
>>> myfunc(1.1)
1.1
0.1
>>> myfunc(-123)
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you AJ! Appreciate your time.

Comment: @Syedscodes1 no problem bro, happy to be of help :)